# how do you make a "concurrent queue safe" lazy loader (singleton manager) in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, singleton, thread-safety

I made this class that turns any object into a singleton, but I know that it's not "concurrent queue safe." Could someone please explain to me how to do this, or better yet, show me the code. To be clear I want to know how to use this with operation queues and dispatch queues (NSOperationQueue and Grand Central Dispatch) on **iOS**.

Thanks in advance,

Rich

**EDIT:** I had an idea for how to do it. If someone could confirm it for me I'll do it and post the code. The idea is that proxies make queues all on their own. So if I make a mutable proxy (like Apple does in key-value coding/observing) for any object that it's supposed to return, and always return the same proxy for the same object/identifier pair (using the same kind of lazy loading technique as I used to create the singletons), the proxies would automatically queue up the any messages to the singletons, and make it totally thread safe.

IMHO this seems like a lot of work to do, so I don't want to do it if it's not gonna work, or if it's gonna slow my apps down to a crawl.

Here's my non-thread safe code:

RMSingletonCollector.h

```
//
//  RMSingletonCollector.h
//  RMSingletonCollector
//
//  Created by Rich Meade-Miller on 2/11/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Rich Meade-Miller. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RMWeakObjectRef.h"

struct RMInitializerData {
    // The method may take one argument.
    // required
    SEL designatedInitializer;
    // data to pass to the initializer or nil.
    id data;
};
typedef struct RMInitializerData RMInitializerData;

RMInitializerData RMInitializerDataMake(SEL initializer, id data);

@interface NSObject (SingletonCollector)

// Returns the selector and data to pass to it (if the selector takes an argument) for use when initializing the singleton.
// If you override this DO NOT call super.
+ (RMInitializerData)designatedInitializerForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

@end


@interface RMSingletonCollector : NSObject {

}

+ (id)collectionObjectForType:(NSString *)className identifier:(NSString *)identifier;
+ (id<RMWeakObjectReference>)referenceForObjectOfType:(NSString *)className identifier:(NSString *)identifier;

+ (void)destroyCollection;
+ (void)destroyCollectionObjectForType:(NSString *)className identifier:(NSString *)identifier;

@end

// ==--==--==--==--==Notifications==--==--==--==--==

extern NSString *const willDestroySingletonCollection;
extern NSString *const willDestroySingletonCollectionObject;
```

RMSingletonCollector.m

```
//
//  RMSingletonCollector.m
//  RMSingletonCollector
//
//  Created by Rich Meade-Miller on 2/11/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Rich Meade-Miller. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RMSingletonCollector.h"
#import <objc/objc-runtime.h>

NSString *const willDestroySingletonCollection = @"willDestroySingletonCollection";
NSString *const willDestroySingletonCollectionObject = @"willDestroySingletonCollectionObject";

RMInitializerData RMInitializerDataMake(SEL initializer, id data) {
    RMInitializerData newData;
    newData.designatedInitializer = initializer;
    newData.data = data;
    return newData;
}

@implementation NSObject (SingletonCollector)

+ (RMInitializerData)designatedInitializerForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    return RMInitializerDataMake(@selector(init), nil);
}

@end


@interface RMSingletonCollector ()

+ (NSMutableDictionary *)singletonCollection;
+ (void)setSingletonCollection:(NSMutableDictionary *)newSingletonCollection;

@end


@implementation RMSingletonCollector

static NSMutableDictionary *singletonCollection = nil;

+ (NSMutableDictionary *)singletonCollection {
    if (singletonCollection != nil) {
        return singletonCollection;
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *collection = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    [self setSingletonCollection:collection];
    [collection release];
    return singletonCollection;
}

+ (void)setSingletonCollection:(NSMutableDictionary *)newSingletonCollection {
    if (newSingletonCollection != singletonCollection) {
        [singletonCollection release];
        singletonCollection = [newSingletonCollection retain];
    }
}

+ (id)collectionObjectForType:(NSString *)className identifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    id obj;
    NSString *key;
    if (identifier) {
        key = [className stringByAppendingFormat:@".%@", identifier];
    }
    else {
        key = className;
    }

    if (obj = [[self singletonCollection] objectForKey:key]) {
        return obj;
    }
    // dynamic creation.
    // get a class for 
    Class classForName = NSClassFromString(className);
    if (classForName) {
        obj = objc_msgSend(classForName, @selector(alloc));
        // if the initializer takes an argument...
        RMInitializerData initializerData = [classForName designatedInitializerForIdentifier:identifier];
        if (initializerData.data) {
            // pass it.
            obj = objc_msgSend(obj, initializerData.designatedInitializer, initializerData.data);
        }
        else {
            obj = objc_msgSend(obj, initializerData.designatedInitializer);
        }
        [singletonCollection setObject:obj forKey:key];
            [obj release];
    }
    else {
        // raise an exception if there is no class for the specified name.
        NSException *exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"com.RMDev.RMSingletonCollector.failed_to_find_class" reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SingletonCollector couldn't find class for name: %@", [className description]] userInfo:nil];
        [exception raise];
        [exception release];
    }
    return obj;
}

+ (id<RMWeakObjectReference>)referenceForObjectOfType:(NSString *)className identifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    id obj = [self collectionObjectForType:className identifier:identifier];
    RMWeakObjectRef *objectRef = [[RMWeakObjectRef alloc] initWithObject:obj identifier:identifier];
    return [objectRef autorelease];
}

+ (void)destroyCollection {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [singletonCollection copy];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:willDestroySingletonCollection object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    [userInfo release];
    // release the collection and set it to nil.
    [self setSingletonCollection:nil];
}
+ (void)destroyCollectionObjectForType:(NSString *)className identifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    NSString *key;
    if (identifier) {
        key = [className stringByAppendingFormat:@".%@", identifier];
    }
    else {
        key = className;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:willDestroySingletonCollectionObject object:[singletonCollection objectForKey:key] userInfo:nil];
    [singletonCollection removeObjectForKey:key];
}

@end
```

RMWeakObjectRef.h

```
//
//  RMWeakObjectRef.h
//  RMSingletonCollector
//
//  Created by Rich Meade-Miller on 2/12/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Rich Meade-Miller. All rights reserved.
//

// In order to offset the performance loss from always having to search the dictionary, I made a retainable, weak object reference class.

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol RMWeakObjectReference <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) id objectRef;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSString *className;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSString *objectIdentifier;

@end


@interface RMWeakObjectRef : NSObject <RMWeakObjectReference>
{
    id objectRef;
    NSString *className;
    NSString *objectIdentifier;
}
- (RMWeakObjectRef *)initWithObject:(id)object identifier:(NSString *)identifier;

- (void)objectWillBeDestroyed:(NSNotification *)notification;


@end
```

RMWeakObjectRef.m

```
//
//  RMWeakObjectRef.m
//  RMSingletonCollector
//
//  Created by Rich Meade-Miller on 2/12/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Rich Meade-Miller. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RMWeakObjectRef.h"
#import "RMSingletonCollector.h"

@implementation RMWeakObjectRef

@dynamic objectRef;
@synthesize className, objectIdentifier;

- (RMWeakObjectRef *)initWithObject:(id)object identifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSString *classNameForObject = NSStringFromClass([object class]);
        className = classNameForObject;
        objectIdentifier = identifier;
        objectRef = object;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(objectWillBeDestroyed:) name:willDestroySingletonCollectionObject object:object];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(objectWillBeDestroyed:) name:willDestroySingletonCollection object:[RMSingletonCollector class]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)objectRef {
    if (objectRef) {
        return objectRef;
    }
    objectRef = [RMSingletonCollector collectionObjectForType:className identifier:objectIdentifier];
    return objectRef;
}

- (void)objectWillBeDestroyed:(NSNotification *)notification {
    objectRef = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [className release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: I really don't get what is the point of such complexity? Why do you need singleton collector if there is only one instance of each class, that has singleton?

Comment: what this does is it allows you to keep a global cache of lazily loaded objects. If your app requires lots of lazily loaded objects that need to be used by multiple parts of your program, this is a place to keep them, instead of having to make a singleton class. Also, this allows you to use Foundation (and UIKit with a little tweaking) types as lazily loaded singletons (think about dictionaries and view controllers).

Comment: Ok, singletons are loaded lazily, but usually after loading they stay in memory until the program termination. So I still don't understand the reason why you want to have a global cache of singletons. Please explain, cause I'm really interested. From other side you can use some modification of Factory pattern: get object from cache by name (and load it if needed). However the returned object is not singleton. In this case there is only one singleton - your global cache manager, that loads other objects.

Comment: I'm sorry I've used the wrong wording, I'm not going to cache singletons, I'm going to cache regular NSObjects with alloc and init methods. This class gives each object that you give it an identifier. You can make more than one cached object of the same type, but they are keyed by their type. So basically this is just a way of lazily loading objects without storing them in one of your MVC objects or making lots of singletons.

Comment: I've decided to call this RMGlobalCache instead, to describe it better.

Comment: I got it working! I made a dispatch queue in the singletonCollection method (now called globalCache) and I use an atomic CAS to make sure the cache and dispatch queue are only created once (it seems to be faster that @synchronized), @synchronized the purgeCache method, dispatch_sync the initialization part of the public accessor for the cache (collectionObjectForType:identifier:). It seems to work, but I'm still testing different situations.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and thread safe) acces to singleton:

```
static SomeClass* shared_instance;
+(SomeClass*) sharedInstance {
    @synchronized( shared_instance ) {
        if( !shared_instance ) {
            shared_instance = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
            //some additional initialization here
        }
    }

    return shared_instance;
}
```

Edit:
I think particular singleton class would be your best choice. Even for lazy loading. E.g. you need to access some array of users all over your app. Then you can create singleton class:

UserManager:

```
+(UserManager*) sharedManager;

-(NSArray*) allUsers;
-(NSArray*) recentUsers;
-(NSArray*) featuredUsers;

-(void) addUser:(User*) user;
-(void) removeUser:(User*) user;
etc...
```

Then you will be able to access that arrays in every view controller.
You should create singleton for other types.

Comment: You don't seem to get it, I don't want to use singletons, I have too many singletons in my app. Plus the singleton pattern is limiting, This class is highly extensible.